# Kubeflow pipeline crashes because the "argoexec wait" container gets OOMKilled

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow, argo-workflows

I have a Kubeflow pipeline whose first step does nothing but downloads one file. This step always crashes in an out-of-memory error:

> This step is in Error state with this message: OOMKilled (exit code
> 137)

Hoping that I would get [Guaranteed QoS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-qos/#guaranteed), I set the memory limit and request to 4G and the CPU limit and request to 1. However, this is just the *main* container. The pod has also *init* and *wait* containers. These run the `argoexec init` and `argoexec wait` commands and request the following resources:

```
limits:
  cpu: 500m
  memory: 512Mi
requests:
  cpu: 10m
  memory: 32Mi
```

To my surprise, when I look at the pod in the Google Cloud console, it's the *wait* container that has been OOMKilled. Is it possible to set the resource limits and requests for the *wait* container, or any other way to work around the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found two possible reasons for the OOM error.

When I go to the Google Kubernetes Engine console and open the pod that crashed, I can see that it's the argoexec process that has crashed, not the download process. The component saves the downloaded file as an output artifact. `argoexec wait` runs after the component has finished and handles uploading the output artifact. You can also view the message log from the GKE console.

On one occasion the problem occured when the next component tried to use the value of the artifact, instead of its path. The error disappeared after I replaced `inputValue` with `inputPath` in the YAML specification of the component that uses the output of the download component.

On another occasion the problem occurred randomly when the downloaded file was very large. It's not possible to change the memory request for the argoexec container, so I modified the pipeline to pass the data on a persistent volume, instead of saving it as an artifact.